# Is it possible to calculate the required DDoS power to seize a server?

Tags: hacker-experience

I know the DDoS efficiency relies on the victim's firewall version, but it seems even if my DDoS hits for 400 Gbps or 4,000Gbps, I always need to DDoS the server twice to seize it.

Is it possible to calculate the required DDoS power to seize a server prior the attack, considering their firewall version and their hardware?

Comment: For clarity: This is talking about the gameplay mechanic in the game Hacker Experience, not real life DDoSing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, but this in game tool could help:

https://hackerexperience.com/ddostest.html

I believe level 3 NPCs are 1500 or something.

Comment: Posting links as sources and as additional information is always good, but you should really write out the most important part as part of the answer. If the page is ever taken down (or even changes its address) this answer would become nearly useless if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

There is an online calculator available imported to JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oo4ptxso/2/).

You will need to supply your Gbps, Victim's Firewall, Server Count, and Internet values to calculate what you need.

**Note**:  This is data pulled from BitCoder's answer, but it involved me extracting the online calculator and making it work in JSFiddle, so I'm posting it as a separate answer.